# iOS 6, StroryBoards: Updating UITextView on main scene after modal segue

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, modal-dialog, segue

I try to update UITextView text on parent scene after returning from child scene where an user can input the content that should appear after navigating back.

Parent scene:

[image]

Modal segue ->

[image]

Child

After navigating back the methods viewWillAppear or viewDidLoad are not getting called and thus this UITextView controller doesn't get feed with updated data. What is the most clever way to solve this problem. Thank you in advance.

EDIT:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
   [super viewWillAppear:animated];
   NSLog(@"Calling viewWillAppear");
// SQLite access methods and other bla bla bla
}
```

After getting back from child scene, viewWillAppear doesn't get called -> NSLog doesn't print out.

Comment: why isn't viewWillAppear getting called? I believe it should be. Can you post code?

Comment: Cos this is modal segue and these no UINavigation involved I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A modal segue like the one you are describing is technically on screen the whole time, so `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear` are never called.

The best way to get the data from the modal view controller to your main view controller is to use delegation.  Send the data back via an argument of a delegate method (defined in your own custom protocol).  In the implementation of your delegate method, do all your SQLite calls, and call `setNeedsDisplay`, and store the value passed by the modal view controller any way you want.